# Preloading images with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I used [this](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/) tutorial to make image slider at my site. But I have more than 100 images. It will be hard to load everything when page loads. So, any tricks to preload first ~10 images, and when I'll slide to the 9th, for example, load another 10?

Or there is already-prepared plugin for jquery which provides this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery I use this:

```
(function($) {
  var cache = [];

  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)

jQuery.preLoadImages("/images/img01.jpg","/images/img02.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

with jquery, something as simple as this works:

```
$('<img />')[0].src = 'image.jpg';
```

it creates an element but never adds it to the page
so the image is loaded, but never shown
check the Net panel in firebug to see it loaded.